# keep indenting when row breaks

Tags: latex, indentation

I can't manage this.

I have a text I want to indent, and keeping indent if the row breaks.Following answers, I tried something like this for my resume, with my "aaa" line I want to keep indenting, in my Work experience section.

This is the second section of the document beginning with \section{\textcolor{myblue}{Work Experience}}

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{0072C6}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\color{myblue}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

\newcommand{\jobtitle}[1]{\textbf{\Huge\uppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\jobtitle{JOB TITLE}\\
\emph{Name - Phone - Email}\\
\end{center}

\vspace{1.5em}

\section{\textcolor{myblue}{Summary}}
\textcolor{mygray}{Description of your experience, skills, and accomplishments.}

\vspace{1.5em}

\section{\textcolor{myblue}{Work Experience}}

\noindent Company \hfill \emph{Date range / Place}

\hangindent0em\hangafter0 \textcolor{mygray}{aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaaa}

\noindent \hangindent3em\hangafter0 \textcolor{mygray}{\textbf{Achievement} - Description of achievement.}\\
\hangindent3em\hangafter0\textcolor{mygray}{\textbf{Skills} - Description of Skills developped.}
\vspace{1em}

\noindent Company \hfill \emph{Date range / Place}

\hangindent0em\hangafter0 \textcolor{mygray}{aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaaa}

\noindent \hangindent3em\hangafter0 \textcolor{mygray}{\textbf{Achievement} - Description of achievement.}\\
\hangindent3em\hangafter0\textcolor{mygray}{\textbf{Skills} - Description of Skills developped.}
\vspace{1em}


\section{\textcolor{myblue}{Education}}

\jobtitle{Degree} in \jobtitle{Field} \hfill Date \\
\textbf{University Name} \hfill City, State \\
\textcolor{mygray}{Honors or other achievements.}

\end{document}
```

And still, my "aaa" line is not aligning
[image]

Comment: Use `\parindent0pt` or `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` to avoid repeating `\noindent`. The paragraph of `aaa ...` has 0 hanging and you still use the default `\parindent`. Remember both `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` affect the current paragraph! BTW have a look at this [blog](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX), which explains how to format paragraphs.

Comment: Besides, I start to believe you are probably using wrong tools. It would also be easier to know what your end goal is. I am not sure if [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the right site for this kind of question. I think you will be better off asking on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX has tools for formatting paragraphs. The following three macros affect paragraph formatting: `\hangindent`, `\hangafter`, and `\parindent`. The latter has a global scope whereas the remaining two works only with a current paragraph. However, you can use `\everypar{}` macro to make a sort of switch so next paragraphs will get the same formatting until next `\everypar`.

`\parindent` controls the indentation of the first line of all paragraphs from the point of issue onward.

Positive length values of `\hangindent` indent text on the left and negative on the right. Positive integers of `\hangafter` keep first `n` lines non-indented, negative only indent first `n` lines and 0 causes the whole paragraph indented. They work only for the current paragraph.

For instance, below is a code that formats 4 paragraphs. The first two share the same formatting: 2 lines are indented at the right with no indentation onward; the next paragraph has all lines indented but the first; and the last paragraph has all lines indented.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\parskip\baselineskip % space between paragraphs
\hsize8cm
\everypar{\hangindent-5em\hangafter-2}
\kant[1][1-2]

\kant[1][3-4]

% Reset everypar
\everypar{}
\parindent15pt

\hangindent6em\hangafter1
\kant[3][1-2]

\parindent0pt
\hangindent3em\hangafter0
\kant[2][1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Celdor, but still. I am doing same thing but it is not working..., see my edit.